# Point Router To Node.js Server

Tags: node.js, dns, router

I am trying to build a local test environment where my local devices will point to a different environment than production. The easiest way for me to do this is to point the device to a server that will map all routes to the production endpoint, to the staging endpoint.

How can I point my router to a Node.js instance, and use the Node.js instance as the DNS server?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're basically wanting to set up a (temporary?) alias for a host name on your local network so that all devices on your network use that alias. For example, today I might want to go to `http://application.example.com` and access the development version; tomorrow I will want to go to the same address and access the testing version.

There are a couple of different ways to do this:

1. Add a proxy - this will take HTTP requests for one host and route them to a different host. You could do this with a virtual machine, a Docker container, or directly on the development/testing machine. All you need to do is point your application domain at the proxy and configure the proxy to send the requests to the server you want.
2. Configure your router to serve the test environment IP address - some routers permit you to add host names to the DNS configuration. This would allow you to simply switch the IP address for the test and development environments as needed, while keeping the same host name.
3. Add a DNS server to your local network - this is basically the same as the item above, except that it gives you much more control (and is more difficult to configure).

All of these will take some work to set up and will depend very much on your server and network setup.